# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CSR_UpdateDailyCustomerWithLCDHistory]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @person_id numeric(18, 0),
    @last_contact_date datetime,
    @source nvarchar(50),
    @callLogId int,
    @createdBy nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN...END
```

In my code I call this stored procedure:

```
public void UpdateDailyCustomerWithLCDHistory(string callerId, 
    int callLogId, string csrName)
{
    try
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase
           ("MarketingWriteConnectionString");
        DbCommand dbCommand = 
           db.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_CSR_UpdateDailyCustomerWithLCDHistory");
        dbCommand.CommandTimeout = AppSetting.Instance.GetCommandTimeout();

        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "person_id", DbType.Decimal, callerId);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "last_contact_date", DbType.Date,
            DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "source", DbType.String, "CSR");
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "callLogId", DbType.Int32, callLogId);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "createdBy", DbType.String, csrName);

        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
    }
}
```

And this is my table's structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDailyCustomerLastContactDateHistory](
    [person_id] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [source] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [callLogId] [int] NULL,
    [createdBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [last_contact_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

After I deploy my application, I got the error

> *Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal*

quite often, not all the time though. Can anybody tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `callerId`?

Comment: What type is `callerId`?

Comment: The first thing you have to do is analyse the data being sent to the stored procedure when it fails and compare that to the cases when it succeeds. There will be a difference and that difference will give you a clue as to what it going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void UpdateDailyCustomerWithLCDHistory(string callerId, int callLogId, string csrName)
{
    try
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MarketingWriteConnectionString");
        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_CSR_UpdateDailyCustomerWithLCDHistory");
        dbCommand.CommandTimeout = AppSetting.Instance.GetCommandTimeout();

        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "person_id", DbType.Decimal, callerId);
```

the callId is a string, you need convert it the decimal before you assign to the value.

you can use Decimal.TryParse() to convert string to Decimal number.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use an `INT` for an Id instead of `NUMERIC` (decimal) field, if you want a numeric identifier. Unless you'll be having Ids that are 1.2, 1.3, etc.

Also, take a look at `AddWithValue` - you won't have to specify a type in  your .NET code. The framework will handle that for you.

Lastly, if `callerId` isn't a matching type, you should either change it or at the least, convert it.